# JMenuItem updating without restarting the client

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem

This code adds the user's favorited songs to a JmenuItem from an ArrayMap

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    String cmd = evt.getActionCommand();
    if (cmd != null) {
        if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("Favorite song")) {
            Music.f.add(Music.s);
            System.out.println(Music.s + " added to favorites");
            System.out.println(Music.f + " current list");

        }
    }
}
    public void initUI() {
    try {
    //...

        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("Music And Sound Options");
        JMenu favorites = new JMenu("Favorite songs");

        for (String name : Music.f) {
            JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(name);
            menuItem.addActionListener(this);
            favorites.add(menuItem);
        }


        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenuBar jmenubar = new JMenuBar();

        frame.add(jmenubar);
        menuBar.add(favorites);
        frame.getContentPane().add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true); // can see the client

        init();
        //...
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

I want the list of songs to update after a song is added, instead of having to restart the client to see more songs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//JMenu favorites = new JMenu("Favorite songs");    
favorites = new JMenu("Favorite songs");
```

The Favorites menu needs to be defined as a class variable. Then when you do this your ActionListener can now reference the menu and add a new menu item to the menu.

```
if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("Favorite song")) {
    Music.f.add(Music.s);
    System.out.println(Music.s + " added to favorites");
    System.out.println(Music.f + " current list");
    JMenuItem item = new JMenItem(...);
    favorites.add( item );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store a reference to your `JMenuBar` as a class field, you can call `menuBar.removeAll()` and repopulate it with new menu items whenever you want (though make sure you do it on the Swing thread when you do, using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` or your Swing method of choice).

Comment: There is no need to use invokeLater because code from a listener is executed on the EDT.

Comment: Right; I missed that OP wanted this to happen inside a listener method. That's what I get for doing too many things at once...